# Can't execute downloaded applescript file

Tags: applescript, volume, mount

I've made an executeable .app file from the applescript editor, which has the purpose to mount an volume. It works as it should on my own Mac, but when I send the file with email or people downloads it from dropbox, they get the error message: "Can't run the file, because the classic-enviroment isn't supportet anymore".

Why do I get this message, and what to do to prevent it?

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? What version of OS X are the other people using? Did you create an archive (a ZIP file) of the .app file before transferring it to the other people?

Comment: I'm using Mountain Lion and not using zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to @NSGod's question tells us what we need to know, probably. You should right-click on the .app file and select 'Compress "NameOfYourApp"' then upload the zip archive. This will ensure that all the conventions and resources are intact when the file is unzipped on the other end. You just can't trust something like dropbox to maintain Mac-specific items, especially when it comes to bundles (".app"s are a type of bundle).

Comment: Thx for the info about mail (and internett i general) can harme the .app bundle